# How to trigger Elementor Popup based on specific url

Tags: javascript, wordpress, popup, elementor

I have a one page website with different sections and few simple popup which are triggered when user clicks on link/button on a page. I want same popup to open when user access website with a specific url example

1. [www.example.com/#menu](http://www.example.com/#menu)
2. [www.example.com/#privacy-policy](http://www.example.com/#privacy-policy)

I found setting under Elementor popup `when arriving from specific URL` but this option is not working for me.

I can do same using custom JavaScript unless it will not work with elementor feature.

I tried different combination of url such as `https://www.example.com/#menu` `#menu` `https://example.com/#menu`

its not working for any combination.

I did keep condition setting also as `Entire site` etc..

Just need a point as i could not find any specify article regarding this as most of the article are about how to trigger popup from link.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found on [GitHub](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/16470) an workaround using URL parameters.

Add the following code as an Elementor HTML Block:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      if (params.get('VARIABLE') === 'OPTION') {
        setTimeout(function() {
          elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: 'POP_ID' } );
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
</script>
```

Change the VARIABLE and the OPTION to your specific parameters, then your URL will be like this:
http://www.example.com/?VARIABLE=OPTION

Also, change the POP_ID to your elementor popup ID which you can find at [Models -> Popups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fOvg.png) (937 in my case) on Wordpress Dashboard, or via inspect.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a class on the section you want.
2. Go to Popup triggers
3. Check "On scroll to element" en put the class in.

Now the pop up show op when you scroll on the section.